# Vite + Solana wallet adapter

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, vite

Does the WalletConnectButton work with vite? Everything seems to work fine in dev, but after build and deploy the button is disabled and does not allow me to connect.

This behavior is similar to what happens when a browser does not have a compatible wallet extension installed, but in this case, I have confirmed that the extension is installed and functioning in the browser.

```
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [nodePolyfills({include: ['stream'], globals: {Buffer: true, process: true}})],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      plugins: [
        nodePolyfills({
          include: ['stream'],
          globals: {
            Buffer: true,
            process: true,
          }
        })
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Would be helpful if you could share your package versions

Answer (score 2):

this works for me.

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { nodePolyfills } from 'vite-plugin-node-polyfills'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [nodePolyfills(), react()],
})
```